# I'm new to python, I can't tell if this will work or not

Tags: python

```
import time
varthing = 1
while varthing == 1:
    time.sleep(60)
    checker = time.strftime("%b, %d", time.localtime())
    if checker == "Dec, 25" :
        print "It's Christmas"
        raw_input("Enter anything to close\n")
        varthing = 0
```

It works from what I can tell, but It's hard to test if this will work long-term.

Comment: Change your clock while the program's running.

Comment: Welcome to SO. re-POSTing [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381192/i-have-no-idea-what-is-wrong-with-this-code) is considered harmful in SO. If you need to include something more you can always edit the original questions

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll work -- though you have the day of Christmas wrong! :) As Michael suggested, you can test by changing your clock (or using tomorrow's date and leaving it overnight).

Here's a somewhat cleaner version:

```
import time
while time.strftime('%b, %d', time.localtime()) != 'Dec, 24':
    time.sleep(60)
print "It's Christmas"
raw_input("Enter anything to close\n")
```

Another approach would be to calculate the number of seconds until Christmas morning and then just `time.sleep()` that amount. Or, for increased robustness to e.g. changing your clock time, `time.sleep()` half the time and then repeat (taking care to stop the halving once it got small enough).

Comment: Lies, it's all the anglophonic countries that celebrate it a day late.

Comment: Sorry :) import time
varthing = 1
while varthing == 1:
    time.sleep(60)
    checker = time.strftime("%b, %d", time.localtime())
    if checker == "Dec, 25" :
        print "It's Christmas"
        raw_input("Enter anything to close\n")
        varthing = 0

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, putting code in comments doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, conceptually your code is ok. Your biggest mistake is that Christmas is (typically) December 25. Nevertheless, here are a few things you can do to make your code a bit more concise:

```
import time
continueLooping = True
while continueLooping:
    time.sleep(60)
    dateChecker = time.strftime("%b, %d", time.localtime())
    if dateChecker == "Dec, 25":
        print "It's Christmas"
        raw_input("Enter anything to close\n")
        continueLooping = False
```

Changes:

- `varthing` -> `continueLooping` : You want your variable names to reflect their intended purpose.
- `= 1; == 1; = 0` -> `= True; ; = False` : Booleans exist for a reason. They make your code more explicit and easier to read. Also, you have to write less code (<strike>`== 1`</strike>).
- `checker` -> `dateChecker` : Your variable names should be specific to their use case (just incase you need to check something else down the line)
- `"Dec, 24"` -> `"Dec, 25"` : Again, Christmas is often December 25.

Otherwise, it's ultimately fine. The `raw_input` bit doesn't seem to do much, but that's a UX thing.

**Edit:**

Seeing as how there's always a smaller way, I'm going to try this as succinctly as possible (without great loss to legibility).

```
import time
while time.strftime("%b, %d", time.localtime()) != "Dec, 25":
    time.sleep(60)
print "It's Christmas"
```

And now I think I'm going to put this up on [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/is-it-christmas-code-golf).

Comment: Yeah the Dec, 24 was a mistake.

Comment: `break` also exists for a reason.

Comment: Python would also typically use variable names like `date_checker` instead of `dateChecker`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def isChristmas(t):
...     return t.month == 12 and t.day == 25
... 
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.today()
datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 4, 19, 49, 48, 51455)
>>> isChristmas(datetime.today())
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import time
T = datetime.datetime(year=2011, month=12, day=25, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
interval = 60
delta = T-datetime.datetime.now()
while delta > datetime.timedelta(0):
   print "T minus "+str(delta)
   if delta.total_seconds() < 60:
      time.sleep(min(1, delta.total_seconds()))
   elif delta.total_seconds() < 60+interval:
      time.sleep(delta.total_seconds()-60)
   else:
      time.sleep(interval)
   delta = T-datetime.datetime.now()

print str(datetime.datetime.now())
raw_input("XMAS!!!")
```

With adaptive sleep, so you have seconds-wise countdown in the last remaining minute.
The min() lets the script fire at almost precisely the desired point in time.

I like it :) - I sometimes just cannot resist to solve some weird problem the way how I would solve it if I really had it...