# I have no idea what is wrong with this code?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm new to python, I can't tell if this will work or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379805/im-new-to-python-i-cant-tell-if-this-will-work-or-not)

```
import time
from sys import stdout
varthing = 1
while varthing == 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    checker = time.strftime("\r%b, %d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    print checker,
    stdout.flush()
    if checker == "Dec, 25 00:00:00" :
        print "It's Christmas"
        raw_input("Enter anything to close\n")
        varthing = 0
```

I don't see anything wrong. It is a clock the notifies you when Christmas is.

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Nothing happens at all, it just counts, when it hits the specified date, nothing happens.

Answer (score 5):

- Your strftime format starts with `\r`.  Why?  The string you are testing against in the `if` statement will never match because it doesn't start with `\r`.
- `time.sleep(1)` is not guaranteed to sleep for exactly one second.  It might sleep longer and you'll miss the one-second window in which `checker` would match the string you're testing against.

Comment: Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: +1 - on the one-second window thing, my suggestion would be to test for a separately formatted date string that doesn't include the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need prints every second, this will do the trick:

```
import datetime, time
target_date = datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 25)
time_left = target_date - datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(time_left.total_seconds())
print "It's Christmas"
```